# Horizontal scroll in iPhone 6

Tags: ios, css, iphone, wordpress

I used a responsive version of the wordpress twentyten theme for my website, and tweaked some css slightly to display things better.

My site looks fine on iPhone 4 + 5, but when I view it on my bosses iPhone6, the website scrolls horizontally. I'm pretty sure I have the correct css media query size of '`667`', so I'm not sure why the 6's content seems to be expanding over the rightside of the page.

(My site was here: http://www.inspiredental.ca/new/)

And I've made a PasteBin of the CSS for the responsive part: http://pastebin.com/4E6wSA1p

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate the error in a browser but there is one flag I'm seeing in the CSS:

```
#container {
    margin: 0 -320px 0 0;
}
```

Try putting this inside of your media query and test it on your iPhone again to see if that's the problem:

```
#container {
    display: none;
}
```

If you're not wanting to use a framework, you might want to re-write #container like this:

```
#container {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
}
#content {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Having a high negative margin on your main container is just asking for trouble. It's easier to do percentages for containers and sidebars and manipulate them using media queries. The above example lets you have a fixed width for your sidebar while resetting the margin.

Comment: If I hide the container div it just removes the content on the page, but the slider, and forms on the page are still over the edge of the righthand side of the page and scrolling horizontally. It almost looks like the containing div is too large for the viewport, however it adjusts fine on the iPhone 4 & 5, but not the 6, it looks like it's cut off on the right. I've added a screenshot above.

Comment: Try hiding your slider since that's the main thing different in your screenshots.

Comment: I will have to try this on monday as my boss who owns the 6 has now left for the day. But if **all** the content is going outside the edge, then I don't think hiding the slider will make any difference.

Comment: Resizing it in the browser maintains the same padding on both edges, as it seems to for iPhone 4/5. There must be something different about the 6 that I'm not accounting for.